# adding command line option -r

Tags: bash, shell

I want to add a command line option -r, recurse, to this code:

```
for name in *.$1; do
    stripped_name="$(basename "$name" ".$1")"
    mv "$name.$1" "$name.$2"
done
```

So if I enter "change -r txt doc", the command should be executed recursively on any subfolder. For example, if there is a file aaa.txt and a directory y containing files y/bbb.txt and y/ccc.txt....it should result in files aaa.doc, y/bbb.doc and y/ccc.doc.

Also if I don't supply the "-r", it should work as normal.

Does anyone know how to add this to my script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet this is far from ideal, but how about the following?  This uses `find` to get the files to rename, but if you *don't* supply the `-r`, it adds `-maxdepth 1` to the arguments.  Then it uses the `rename(1)` command on Debian based systems (e.g. Ubuntu) to rename the matching files.  The `-print0` and `xargs -0` makes sure that this doesn't have problems with odd filenames that might contain newlines, etc.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ x"$1" = x-r ]
then
    FIND_OPTIONS=""
    shift
else
    FIND_OPTIONS="-maxdepth 1"
fi

FROM="$1"
TO="$2"

find . $FIND_OPTIONS -name '*.'$FROM -print0 | xargs -0 rename "s/\.$FROM/\.$TO/"
```

Comment: I was thinking maybe using a "case" to select -r. I'm thinking about writing it that way. What do you think? BTW, thanks for the suggestion and code Mark.

Comment: I don't think there's any need to use `case` here - the `-r` is either present or not, rather than being one of a several possibilities.